# Python regex extraction

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string called "strtosearch2" like this:

```
[02112017 072755 332][1][ERROR]> ----Message : IDC_NO_MEDIA
[02112017 072755 332][1][INFO]> ----              
[02112017 104502 724][1][ERROR]> ----Message : DEV_NOT_READY
[02112017 104502 724][1][INFO]> ----              
[02112017 104503 331][1][ERROR]> ----Message : DEV_NOT_READY
[02112017 104503 331][1][INFO]> ----
```

I want to extract the dates which are having the lines "ERROR" only. I wrote my regex as follows:

```
down2Date= re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\s\d{6}\s\d{3}\]\[\d\]\[ERROR\]',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)
```

output as follows:

```
02112017
02112017 072755 332][1][INFO]> ----              
[02112017
02112017 104502 724][1][INFO]> ----              
[02112017
```

My target output:

```
02112017
02112017
02112017
```

How can I fix this ?. Thank you

Comment: Remove `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: suggestion: sometimes you don't need to define exact input pattern.. for given sample, `re.findall(r'(?m)^\[(\d+).*ERROR', strtosearch2)` would work too..  if not, try to add relevant sample when asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may anchor the pattern at the start of the line/string and **remove** the `re.DOTALL` modifier:

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^\[(.*?)\s\d{6}\s\d{3}]\[\d]\[ERROR]', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mSxAv/1)

With `re.DOTALL`, the `.` matched any char *including* line break chars.

With `(?m)`, `^` matches the start of each line, not only the start of the whole string.

Also, `\s` can match line break chars, so you might want to use `[^\S\r\n]` instead of it to only match horizontal whitespace.

Comment: Great, Thanks for added details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
down2Date = re.findall(r'^\[\d+\s\d+\s\d+\]\[\d\]\[ERROR\]', strtosearch2)
```

Comment: can anyone specify what does this `re.DOTALL` had affected?

Comment: @Sanket See my answer.

Comment: If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline. Details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)